# sql server regex

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, sql-server-2012

In SQL Server (2012) I have a field with numeric values. The field is of type `int`.
Let's say that the field in the db contains `123456789`.
I'm searching like this:

```
select * from table1 where field1 like '[1-9]{0,2}3456789'
```

I have also tried `'^[1-9]{0,2}$3456789'`

Both are not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Regex is not supported for integer still you can user regex to search a text in SQL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQL Server does not natively support Regular Expressions. You would need to install a CLR assembly for this.

The `LIKE` pattern syntax does not support quantifiers so without using CLR the only alternative is to expand it out.

```
where field1 like '3456789' 
 or  field1 like '[1-9]3456789'  
 or  field1 like '[1-9][1-9]3456789'
```

Comment: using the "or  field1 like" few times will hurt the performance?

Comment: @Itay.B - It will process the string multiple times so won't be as efficient as a RegEx. Installing a CLR assembly is quite easy though.

Comment: @RoyiNamir - No but that's the same as just having a `LIKE` without a leading and trailing wildcard isn't it?

Comment: If i want to use a clr assembly i need the dba to approve it, which in my company is not an easy task.