# Trying to find an alternative to likes and not likes (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT.....

 (v1.PCG like 'n0%'
or
v1.PCG like 'n1%'
or
v1.PCG like 'n2%'
or
v1.PCG like 'n3%'
or
v1.PCG like 'n4%'
or
v1.PCG like 'n5%'
or v1.PCG='N63Af1')

and v1.PCG not like 'N2D%'
and v1.PCG not like 'N2E%'
and v1.PCG not like 'N2C%'
and v1.PCG not like 'N2F%'
and v1.PCG not like 'N2J%'
and v1.PCG not like 'N2K%'
and v1.PCG not like 'N2U%'
and v1.PCG not like 'N2GC%'
and v1.PCG not like 'N2GD%'
and v1.PCG not like 'N2GH%'
and v1.PCG not like 'N2GJ%'
and v1.PCG not like 'N2GK%'
) as 'Value Of PN Orders',

from........
```

I have competed my code but am trying to find a more effecient way of doing this, i had a look but cannot find another way...Any suggestions?

Comment: A regular expression can make this much more compact, but it's not native to SQL Server. You'll need to do it via [a CLR assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13439423/1324345)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Like` supports character classes so;

```
where v1.PCG like 'n[12345]%'
```

Comment: For additional details on the syntax see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Comment: @AlexK. . . . This only addresses part of the `where` clause.  You should expand the answer for the entire clause.

Answer (score 2):

This particular case can be worked with wildcards - not really requiring regular expressions:

```
(v1.PCG LIKE 'n[0-5]%' OR v1.PCG='N63Af1')
AND v1.PCG NOT LIKE 'N2[CDEFJKU]%'
AND v1.PCG NOT LIKE 'N2G[CDHJK]%'
```

An alternative that wouldn't change the semantics much, but would read cleaner, would be to use a table variable or CTE to JOIN to:

```
 DECLARE @match TABLE (Value varchar(5))
 INSERT @match VALUES 
    ('N0%'),
    ('N1%'),
    ('N2%'),
    ('N3%'),
    ('N4%'),
    ('N5%'),
    ('N63Af1')

 DECLARE @not TABLE (Value varchar(5))
 INSERT @not VALUES 
    ('N2D%'),
    ('N2E%'),
    ('N2C%'),
    ('N2F%'),
    ('N2J%'),
    ('N2K%'),
    ('N2U%'),
    ('N2GC%'),
    ('N2GD%'),
    ('N2GH%'),
    ('N2GJ%'),
    ('N2GK%')

SELECT ...
JOIN @match ON
     v1.PCG LIKE @match.Value
LEFT OUTER JOIN @not ON
     v1.PCG NOT LIKE @not.Value
WHERE
     @not.Value IS NULL
```

That's a good trick if your values are user-supplied. In this case, though, I think the wildcard sets win out for ease of use.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a job for **[regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx)**

Comment: -1. Please don't give lik-only answers. Links break and the answer becomes useless. Besides that does not answer the question. It only redirects to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CONTAINS() Predicate in the WHERE CLAUSE in your T-SQL query.

```
SELECT <<COLUMNS>>
FROM   <<TABLE>>
WHERE CONTAINS(<<COLUMN TO SEARCH>>, <<VALUE TO SEARCH>>);
```

Read further here at:
[MSDN : CONTAINS (T-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx)