# Sql Server regular expression in select

Tags: sql-server, regex

I am looking to use a regex with sqlserver in a select Statment in SQL Server V 2008+.

what i would need this to do is get the first word of a column.

and a second that would get the rest of the column excluding the first word.

i know this is simple, but i am not very good at regular expressions.

can anyone help me with this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [sql server regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13439397/sql-server-regex)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what regex you will use but:

`^\S+` - for first word
`.+$` - for the rest string

or if pasible grouping can be

`^(\S+) (.+)$` - first parenthesis for first word and second for the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this UDF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/707617/394007) that Marc Gravell provides. It gets you the first word ... you can then create another UDF called "AfterFirstWord".

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex to so something like this. Simply use `SUBSTRING` and `CHARINDEX` and `RIGHT` for the rest of the sentence:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING([COLUMN], 0, CHARINDEX(' ', [COLUMN])),         -- Get substring before first space
    RIGHT([COLUMN], LEN([COLUMN]) - CHARINDEX(' ', [COLUMN])) -- Get substring after first space
FROM
    [TABLE]
```

---

SQL Server doesn't really support regex, though you can find some downloadable libraries online. Otherwise, you have [`PATINDEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395%28v=sql.90%29.aspx), which while it uses regex, it does not return matches, but the index of the match. In your case, it's much easier to use `CHARINDEX` since you will always ever need to match a space character.